# Where can i get the source code for ODK Collect 1.3?

Tags: odk

I cannot find the source code for ODK Collect 1.3, can anyone tell me where I can find the source code. I tried github and i have been searching for hours and i cant seem to be able to find it. I need the source code for odk collect 1.3 as it appears in the play store. I appreciate any help or direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the source code for ODK Collect at https://code.google.com/p/opendatakit/source/browse?repo=collect.

http://code.google.com/p/opendatakit has the rest of the ODK codebase.

Answer (score 0):

It is found here https://github.com/opendatakit and the android collect is here https://github.com/opendatakit/collect